# Are there plans to get ATI stream SDK working properly on BSD?

Tags: freebsd

I have BSD functioning exactly as I would like for workstations/laptops.  I'm looking at getting in to OpenCL applications and would prefer to use BSD with fglrx or some workaround to get opencl working without doubling to cost to get Nvidia cards.  There were plans to get USB passthrough vbox OSE working on BSD for a while and I waited it out.  Great stuff btw.  I'm wondering about opencl on ATI.  I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ATI and AMD does not even published binary drivers for FreeBSD, I doubt that they would do that for ATI Stream SDK.

Comment: Thanks.  I had just noticed that you could get some opencl support for nvidia through linux abstraction and the binary driver, so I thought I would ask.